# ActiveMQ 5.14.5 does not delete pending messages

Tags: java, activemq-classic, journal

I upgrade my ActiveMQ to 5.14.5 but when I start it, I receive an error:

> Failed to start Apache ActiveMQ ([localhost, null],
>   java.io.IOException: Detected missing journal files. [16, 56, 11,
>   108]) | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main

I found that there are pending messages which are not cleared as is expected. If I delete them, activemq starts normally, otherwise I cannot start it.

Do you know how to fix this bug?

Comment: How did you found there are pending messages when you can't start it?

Comment: I use ignoreMissingJournalfiles ="true" to start it. But when i remove it and start again my activemq i have pending messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1."deleting pending messages" is not an expected behavior for activemq. It depends on whether your messages are persistent or not. If it's not persistent, it will get lost with reboot, but persistent messages will survive broker restart.

2.For your case , the situation is some persistent files got lost. The reason may be some files are deleted by accident, or maybe the config of persistent file path being changed. So activemq knows there are some persistent messages, but it can't find where it was stored.

3.ignoreMissingJournalfiles  is just being used for this situation, you got that right.